# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 1?

Tags: java

Necesito que me imprima un arreglo bidimesional de filas y columnas que empiece en 2 y sume 2.

Tiene una falla en la linea 19, imprime cada fila enumerada
..........................................................................................................

```
public class Practicaparaserrevisada {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
          int columna = 0;
          int columnas = 0;
          int dato = 0;
          int dato2 = 0;
          int filas = 0;
          int fila = 0;
          int[][] arreglo = new int[1][1];
          
          filas = 4;
          columnas = 4;
          fila = 1;
          columna = 1;
          arreglo[filas][columnas] = 0;
          dato = 2;
          dato2 = 1;
          
       
          while (fila > filas)
          {
              System.out.println(dato2 + " ");
             while (columna > columnas)
             {
                arreglo[fila][columna] = dato;
                System.out.println(" " + dato + " ");
                dato = dato + 2;
                columna = columna + 1;
             }
             dato2 = dato2 + 1;
             fila = fila + 1;
             columna = 1;
             System.out.println(" ");
             
          }
    }

}
```

Comment: Podrías agregar algo más de descripción, no? Cuál es el resultado esperado, en qué línea falla,  describir con tus palabras qué es lo que intentás hacer y el reusltado esperado... No todos van a tener ganas de seguir tu código antes de responderte, y siempre ayuda que acotes el esfuerzo de quien quiere ayudarte. Podés usar el enlace a [edit] para mejorar la pregunta

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu [primera medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Esta es la declaración de la matriz:

```
  int[][] arreglo = new int[1][1];
```

Es una matriz 1 x 1. Significa que el único valor que se puede asignar está en la posición 0:

```
arreglo[0][0] = 0;
```

Luego haces esta asignación:

```
  arreglo[filas][columnas] = 0;
```

El valor de filas y columnas es 4, esa posición en la matriz no existe. Eso produce la excepción por la cual consultas.